# How can I write a leap-year program in one line using PHP?

Tags: php, leap-year

How can I write a leap-year program in one line using PHP?

Comment: Please define what you mean by a leap-year program? This could mean many things.

Comment: Don't touch the enter key.

Comment: With much use of the ternary operator...

Comment: OK Define Leapyear: If Year %  400=0 Its Leap year If Year % 4 =0 Its also Leapyear and if Year % 100 its not a Leap year

Comment: May I just ask (out of pure curiosity), why only one line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how to **know** it using one line of code :)

```
print (date("L") == 1) ? "Leap Year" : "Not Leap Year";
```

Comment: Even shorter: `$isLeapYear = (date("L") == 1);`

Comment: @Gordon: That's true, but i just wanted to print the output :)

Comment: @Gordon - date("L") returns bool already.  `$isLeapYear = date("L");` is all you need.

Comment: @thetaiko Not bool. String. `var_dump(date('L')); // string(1) "0"`. But since 1 and 0 would be typecasted as needed, yes, I agree it can be shortened even further.

Answer (score 5):

`if (($year % 400 === 0) || (($year % 100 !== 0) && ($year % 4 === 0))) echo "leap";`

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220163/how-to-find-leap-year/#11595914

`if (year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0)
    {
        /* leap year */
    }`

Comment: I would not want to maintain that code. Bit operations for something that is only arithmetic are cryptic. The original answer you quote considered performance, so it might be relevant in some cases. But for all other cases, I'd rather keep a readable expression.

Comment: I usually place a URL in a comment when something is cryptic; or, place the code in a function like "IsLeapYear" where it is clear what it does. Since the Gregorian Calendar isn't changing any time soon, I don't think "maintainability" is much of a concern. This code can be more than twice as fast, and even ten times faster in 8-bit embedded system CPUs where there is no divide instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no limit in how long a line of code is, unless you are using a code convention like that of Zend Framework, you can use whatever works and write into one line. Of course, depending on the functionality of your *leap-year program*, this will likely be hard to maintain. I've seen legacy code running over 800 chars with PHP, HTML and CSS intermingled. Eye-bleeding, I can tell you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$nextyear  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't know the meaning of leap-year, sorry. But I'll keep this "answer" here in case people end up here with the question that I thought you asked!

Answer (score 2):

`echo date("L");`

Answer (score 1):

date("L"); is even shorter.

```
if(date("L")){
   //leap year
} else {
   //not leap year
}
```