# SQL Server : is there a way for me to get weeks per month using Month and Year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not really good when it comes to database...

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the weeks of a certain month and year..

For example: `1 (January)` = `month` and `2016` = `year`

Desired result will be:

```
week 1
week 2
week 3
week 4
week 5
```

This is what I have tried so far...

```
declare @date datetime = '01/01/2016'
select datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, @date) / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1
```

This only returns the total of the weeks which is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @MonthStart datetime
-- Find first day of current month
set @MonthStart = dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)

select
    Week,
    WeekStart = dateadd(dd,(Week-1)*7,@MonthStart)
from
    ( -- Week numbers
    select Week = 1 union all select 2 union all
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
    ) a
where
    -- Necessary to limit to 4 weeks for Feb in non-leap year
    datepart(mm,dateadd(dd,(Week-1)*7,@MonthStart)) =
    datepart(mm,@MonthStart)
```

Got the answer in the link: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1328013-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to approach this:

A month has a minimum of 29 or more days, and a max of 31 or less. Meaning there are almost always 5 weeks a month, with the exception of a non-leap year's feburary, and in those cases, 4 weeks a month.

You can refer to this to find out which years are "leap".
[Check for leap year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534788/check-for-leap-year)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to select a start and end date, and output one row per week, with numbered weeks, between those dates:

```
declare @start date = '1/1/2016'
declare @end date = '5/1/2016'

;with cte as (select @start date
                    , datename(month, @start) as month
              union all
              select dateadd(dd, 7, date)
              , datename(month, dateadd(dd, 7, date))
              from CTE
              where date <= @end
              )

 select *, 'week ' 
   + cast(row_number() over (partition by month order by date) as varchar(1))
from CTE
order by date
```