# Need to find out the date 1 year and 1 year ago from today in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find out the date 1 year and 1 day ago from today in T-SQL. I have done the following but I keep getting errors.

```
select DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)), 
DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
```

Can someone please assist. Thanks.

Comment: add the sql-server tag. Alsom you don't need to cast getdate to date and then to datetime; it is already a datetime

Comment: `select  DATEADD(DAY, - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, GETDATE()) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it like this:

```
select dateadd(year,-1,dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the *date*, then convert to date:

```
select convert(date, dateadd(year, -1, getdate() - 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -366, GETDATE())
```

**EDIT:**

Updated code as per comments, (used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534788/check-for-leap-year) )

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(CAST(@YEAR AS char(4)) + '0229') = 1 
THEN
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -367, GETDATE())
ELSE 
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -366, GETDATE())
END
```

Comment: And what about leap years?

Comment: You will have a propblem on leap years since they have 366 days.

Comment: This is wrong, what about needing this when we are no longer in leap year? You can't expect to remember to change this on time before a break every few years. And this doesn't check on the full leap year, it only checks on leap year day, meaning this will result incorrect every other day.