# Is it possible to declare a variable that is visible across all database objects when used in a query, stored procedures, functions, etc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I need to pull daily prorated amounts from various tables for custom periods.

For example I need to pull values from March 1, 2018 to April 30, 2019. Some years are leap years and, some are not. So, I would use

```
SELECT amount / CASE WHEN Year(start_date) % 4 = 0 THEN 366 ELSE 365 END..
```

Is it possible to declare a variable instead of that CASE statement and I could use it in every query, stored procedure, function, trigger...

```
SELECT amount / @some_var...
```

Thank you,
Gene

UPDATE:
I know that I can not use the formula above for a leap year calculation because the result of it is not always true. This is just an example, sorry, may be not a good one. I am more interested if it is possible to declare some sort of variable, like environment variable in windows, that I can use across queries.

Comment: Why? Variables in all programming languages are meant to hold values inside a single method or script. In any case the leap year calculation would be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for leap year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534788/check-for-leap-year)

Comment: Why not just do `SELECT amount / DATEDIFF(DAY, start_date, DATEADD(YEAR,1,start_date))`?

Comment: I know that I can not use that formula for a leap year as it is not always the true. This is just an example, sorry, may be not a good one. I am more interested if it is possible to declare some sort of variable that I can use across queries.

Comment: You can store values in tables...

Comment: Values in a database are kept in tables.  Put values like this there.

Answer (score 0):

Most data warehouses have a date table that has a row for each date with date attributes as columns like date,FiscalYear,CalendarYear,FQ,CQ,....

You would then use that in your query like the following.

```
cross apply (
select Count(*) NumOfDays from DimDate
where CalendarYear = YEAR(start_date) ) ca
```

then you can use ca.NumOfDays wherever you need it.

Comment: I updated my question. I guess that example was not a good one. I am more interested if there is a possibility to use some sort of globally declared variable that I could use across my queries.

Comment: That is a description of a function then

Comment: Functions can be heavy for large data sets. I have been using them a lot and I would like to cut down on the usage.