# Number Of Days in a month of particular year Not Working

Tags: java, date, java-8

**Note**: *Donot mark it duplicate, I know it is duplicate question but I didn't get help from [**it**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438/number-of-days-in-particular-month-of-particular-year)*.

I want to calculate Number Of Days in a month of particular year. I read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438/number-of-days-in-particular-month-of-particular-year) and but it is **NOT** working fine. I tried following

```
public class NumOfDays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter month: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);

        System.out.println("Number of days are: " + mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }
}
```

My Console is

```
Enter month: 2
Enter year: 2000
Number of days are: 31 /// Wrong
```

and

```
Enter month: 10
Enter year: 1999
Number of days are: 30 // Correct
```

I know that there are one other method i.e. to calculate it manually, but I want to do it like above. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

P.S: I am using JAVA-8.

Comment: `mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` doesn't return number of days

Comment: It might be helpful to explain exactly why this is not a duplicate, and why the question you linked to, didn't help you.

Comment: @JigarJoshi thank, I updated my question ... problem still there.

Comment: Why not taking the 1st day of the next month then substract 1 day and see what is the current day?

Comment: months starts from 0, so 2 is March

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wasn't there 31 days in March 2000? Month is zero based, as the doc say (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar-int-int-int-)

Edit: I'm stupid, I thought you had the number of days in a month figured out. You need to use getActualMaximum, not get. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#getActualMaximum-int-)

Comment: You still need to substract 1 to your month, since you expect a user to start at 1, but Java starts at 0.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using Java 8 I suggest using the new date/time API, java.time, specifically its [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2000, 2);
System.out.println(ym.lengthOfMonth()); //29 as expected
```

Comment: Even better than mine

Answer (score 0):

following will work for sure...

public class NumberOfDays

{

public static void main(String g[])

{

Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int days,month,year,date;

    System.out.println("enter year= ");
    year=scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("enter month= ");
    month=scanner.nextInt();

    date=1;

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(year, (month-1), date);

    days=calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    System.out.println("max day= "+days);
}
```

}