# Collect the number of days per month in each month in a span of time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I m stuck in this for days i searched a lot, I use jodatime library in a java swing programme 
so here is what i need
from 2013-04-17 to 2013-05-21
I need to output the result like this :

- April 2013 (Days number = 14)
- Mai 2013 (Days number = 21)

I tried a lot but no solution, got mad :( delete all code and came here for help
any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This will help you to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438/number-of-days-in-particular-month-of-particular-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team has advised us to migrate to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time framework has been [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse ( "2013-04-17" );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse ( "2013-05-21" );
if ( stop.isBefore ( start ) ) {
    System.out.println ( "ERROR - stop before start" );
    // FIXME: Handle error.
}
```

The [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents, well, a year and a month combined. Perfect for tracking your desired results. Using this class makes your code type-safe with guaranteed valid values as opposed to using mere strings or numbers.

```
YearMonth startYm = YearMonth.from ( start );
YearMonth stopYm = YearMonth.from ( stop );
```

We create a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) where a `YearMonth` key maps to a `Integer` value (the number of days) to collect our results. [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is our chosen implementation.

```
SortedMap<YearMonth , Integer> map = new TreeMap<> ();
```

The example code does not assume we are bridging only a pair of months. If multiple months are in between, we ask `YearMonth` for the number of days in that month. We loop `YearMonth` by `YearMonth`, obtaining a number of days each time.

We do if-else tests for each of five possible cases:

- Single month

  - The start and stop are within a single month.
- Multiple months

  - On first month
  - On any in-between months
  - On last month
- Impossible `else`

  - Should be impossible to reach unless we made a mistake in our logic or coding.

In each case we capture the number of days to collect for that `YearMonth`.

When calling the `between` method, we must adjust for its use of the Half-Open approach to handling spans of time. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Generally this is the best route. But the logic in the Question is otherwise, so we adjust. I strongly suggest undoing these adjustments and instead adjust your inputs. Consistent use of Half-Open will make date-time handling much easier.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = startYm;
do {
    int days = 0;
    if ( startYm.equals ( stopYm ) ) { // If within the same (single) month.
        days = ( int ) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , stop );
    } else if ( yearMonth.equals ( startYm ) ) { // If on the first month of multiple months, count days.
        days = ( int ) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , startYm.plusMonths ( 1 ).atDay ( 1 ) ); //  Get first of next month, to accommodate the `between` method’s use of Half-Open logic.
    } else if ( yearMonth.isAfter ( startYm ) && yearMonth.isBefore ( stopYm ) ) { // If on the in-between months, ask for the days of that month.
        days = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth ();
    } else if ( yearMonth.equals ( stopYm ) ) {  // If on the last of multiple months.
        days = ( int ) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( stopYm.atDay ( 1 ).minusDays ( 1 ) , stop ); // Get last day of previous month, to accommodate the `between` method’s use of Half-Open logic.
    } else {
        System.out.println ( "ERROR - Reached impossible point." );
        // FIXME: Handle error condition.
    }
    map.put ( yearMonth , days ); // Cast long to int, auto-boxed to Integer.
    // Prep for next loop.
    yearMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths ( 1 );
} while (  ! yearMonth.isAfter ( stopYm ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start: " + start + " | stop: " + stop + " | map: " + map );
```

> start: 2013-04-17 | stop: 2013-05-21 | map: {2013-04=14, 2013-05=21}