# Get the number of days from a joda `YearMonth`

Tags: java, jodatime

Given a `YearMonth` (from `org.joda.time.YearMonth`), is there a easy way to get the number of days in that month?

I saw this thread [Number of days in particular month of particular year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438) and it works fine with the following.

1. Create a `Calendar` object
2. Call `getActualMaximum` with `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`

Like this:

```
YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yearMonth.getYear(), yearMonth.getMonthOfYear(), 1);
int daysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

But I am wondering if there is some utility function in joda that I can just get the days in month directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with this:

```
YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth();
yearMonth.toLocalDate(1).dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
```

---

I haven't tried this and obviously this SO is closed, but please checkout the solution suggested by [nooruddin-khorasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5248895/nooruddin-khorasi) below in the comments too:

```
YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth();
yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
```

Comment: A much better way:

`YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth();
yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();`

Comment: Hey @nooruddinkhorasi, was looking for length of days for this.

Comment: OP was looking for a way to find number of days in any given month.  `lengthOfMonth()` gives the intended number.

Comment: Hey @nooruddinkhorasi, I misunderstood you original comment. Added your suggestion in the answer too. Thanks!