# How to find current month length in Java?

Tags: java, date-format

This is my Java code to find the current month/date we are in:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetCurrentDateTime {

 private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

     }
}
```

I want this code to do something else. When the code finds the month we are in, I also want it to find the month length. Result should be like this:

```
08-16
31
```

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. We would love to help you. But only when we see that you have already tried your best to solve this problem.

Comment: @TAsk That is not a requirement for all Questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of days in particular month of particular year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438/number-of-days-in-particular-month-of-particular-year)

Comment: I tried my best. I know that asking stackoverflow is not the first way to solve problems. I tried my best, I searched for my problems., but I couldn't see the result. So I am asking to you. I don't understand why experienced users act that strict to newbies.

Comment: we want to **see** your best.  Post it here and we can inform you how to fix it

Comment: @jansetk Have a look at my solution

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.now()
         .lengthOfMonth()
```

## Details

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes seen in the Question. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

A time zone is crucial in determining today's date and therefore in determining the current month. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
int daysInMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, but I think, there might be a better way:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
System.out.println(c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Output is this:

```
08-16
31
```

**EDIT:**
As written in the Comments:

Use the solution from Basil `YearMonth.now().lengthOfMonth()`, it's a better way than this

Comment: Use the solution from Basil `YearMonth.now().lengthOfMonth()`, it's a better way than this.

Comment: Really, it's time to put that `Calendar` class in a box and tuck it away at the back of the attic to be ignored and forgotten.

Comment: Shame on me, I didn't even know about ZoneId/YearMonth when I was writing my solution. But you are right, it's a better and clearer way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that:

```
   @Test
    public void daysOfMonthTest() throws Exception {
    Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar();

    assertEquals(
            31,
            mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: The Months are numbered from 0 (January) to 11 (December).**

***Using Simple Date Object:***

```
        Date date = new Date();
        int month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        int year = date.getYear()+1900;
        System.out.print(month+"-"+year);
```

Output:

```
 8-2017
```

***Using Calendar Object:***

```
     Date date = new Date(); // your date
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;
    System.out.print(month+"-"+year);
    System.out.print("Number of days: "+cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Output:

```
8-2017
Number of days: 31
```

***Using JodaTime:***

```
    DateTime  dateTime = new DateTime();
    System.out.print(dateTime.getMonthOfYear()+"-"+(dateTime.getYear()));
    System.out.print("Number of days: "+ dateTime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue());
```

Output:

```
8-2017
Number of days: 31
```

Comment: how does this show the number of days in the current month?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Updated , please check