# How to Get the number of hours between two or more months?

Tags: java, android

Am implementing a default range picker and I would like the user to specify the default duration range

So in my ranges
I have

```
1 day = 24 hours
3 days = 24 * 3 hours
1 week = 24 * 7 hours
1 month
```

My logic is using the total hours in a day and multiply  by total days

But now the problem comes in when the range becomes more than 2 months, since some months have 31 day, 28 days and even 30days

SO how do I go about determining example the last two months from now the number of hours, so that in my calendar I can simply

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) - hours) //stuck here
```

SO in simple terms example

today being april 2, how do I get the number of hours from january 2 to april 2.

SO in my own logic it for more than one month it should look like:

```
 Date today = Date.now();    
 LocalDate userday = LocalDate.of(less number of months); 
 Period diff = Period.between(userday, today);
```

Comment: 1 hour = 24 hours !!!!!!!

Comment: @Lucifer sorry its 1 day

Comment: in that case, how come `1 day = 24 hours` and `3 days = 36 hours`, I think it should be `3 days = 72 hours`

Comment: @Lucifer ive updated the logic, I see my bad math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substract month like below,

```
Date referenceDate = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(currentDate); 
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
return c.getTime();
```

Then get hours from following code.

```
long diff = currentDate.getTime() - previousDate.getTime();
long hours = minutes / (1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: now how do i get the previous date, Since as in the question the user is specifying the duration eg 3 months which mean its 3 months from today, so how will i get the previous date 3 months back from today.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI, any progress ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2018,Calendar.JANUARY, 2);
Long min = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.set(2018,Calendar.APRIL, 2);
Long max = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Long range = (max - min) / (60*60*1000); //no_of_hours
```

Updated Answer:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Long max = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    int currMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int currYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int expMonth = currMonth + 3/*no_of_month*/;
    int expYear = currDate;
    int expDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    while (expMonth > 11) {
        expMonth = expMonth - 12;
        expYear = expYear + 1; // will increment year as next month falls in next year 
    }
    calendar.set(expYear, expMonth, expDate);
    Long min = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    Long range = (max - min) / (60 * 60 * 1000); //no_of_hours
```

Comment: January was just an example the range is dynamic  that is , Jnuary, feb augusut ... etc not a must it be january

Comment: You can set it as required or as selected by user

Comment: the user is specifying a range eg 3 months so am trying to get from the code which are the three months from the current date, the user is not selecting the months

Answer (score 0):

You need the number of days within a month.

Its easy once you determine which month it is:

Take a look at this:
[Number of days in particular month of particular year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438/number-of-days-in-particular-month-of-particular-year)

Once you have the month just calculate number of hours for it and keep adding until you satisfy your range.