# How to get all the dates of every month in Java from LocalDate in a List

Tags: java

I want to get all the dates of a month in a list so i can show all the dates from that month on a JSF page. When the month changes the amount of dates has to change accordingly.

I Use Java 8 LocalDate.

How can i best do that?

Comment: Why not use JSF calendar? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml

Comment: google jsf-datepicker-example

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. But it's not just the calendar widget i need. I need to put the dates into the first column of a datatable

Comment: "When the month changes the amount of dates has to change" > you say that you already want all the dates of all the months. How can a month change after you already have them all? I think you're not describing correctly what's your problem.

Comment: @kumesana I've edited my question a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of days in particular month of particular year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940438/number-of-days-in-particular-month-of-particular-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how can one need to put all the dates of the month in a database, but here's a way to get the List of all the dates of the current month:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
    LocalDate end = date.plusMonths(1);

    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    while(date.isBefore(end)) {
        dates.add(date);
        date = date.plusDays(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks kumesana. That works fine.