# Leap year calculation in C++ for Homework assignment?

Tags: c++, leap-year

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int what_year;

    cout << "Enter calendar year ";
    cin >> what_year;

    if (what_year - (n * 4) = 0 ) {

        cout << "leap year";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "wont work";
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to make a program for class, to find a leap year.. not sure how to ask C++ if an integer is divisible by a number?

Comment: As others mention below, what you're looking for is "modular arithmetic".  It is an operator that gives you the remainder of a divide.  If the remainder is 0, the number is wholly divisible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find leap year programatically in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220163/how-to-find-leap-year-programatically-in-c)

Comment: A handy collection of low-level date algorithms: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#is_leap

Answer (score 9):

The leap year rule is

```
 if year modulo 400 is 0 then
   is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0 then
   not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0 then
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

You can use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to see if one number is evenly divisible by another, that is if there is no remainder from the division.

> 2000 % 400 = 0 // Evenly divisible by 400
>
> 2001 % 400 = 1 // Not evenly divisible by 400

Interestingly, several prominent software implementations did not apply the "400" part, which caused February 29, 2000 not to exist for those systems.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice: Cool optimization.  Too bad Wikipedia won't accept that as an addition to the existing article.

Answer (score 4):

Use the modulo function.

```
if ((year % 4) == 0)
{
//leap year
}
```

Note that this does not account for the 100 and 400 year jump.

Proper code would be something like

```
if(((year%4) == 0) && (((year%100)!=0) || ((year%400) == 0))
{
//leap year
}
```

Comment: My code does account for the 400 year leap year. Assume the year is 2400, then it results in (true && (false || true)) = (true && true) = true.

Comment: Huh.  Yes, your code clearly does the 400 leap year.  I don't know why I didn't see that before. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead

```
bool bLeapYear = false;
if ((what_year % 4) ==0)  {
     if ((what_year % 100) == 0) {
          bLeapYear = ((what_year % 400) == 0);
     } else {
          bLeapYear = true;
     }
     // leap year
}
```

This takes the remainder of the year after dividing by 4 and tests to see if it is zero. You also had a problem using `=` instead of `==` - the latter tests for equality, the former assigns a value.

EDIT: Edited according to the comment of Steve below.

Comment: 1900 is not a leap year, this formula is not correct http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214019

Comment: @Steve Wow, I never knew this information. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Note that, in about 8000 years, the calendar will again be a day behind. Not our problem, though :)

Answer (score 1):

According to some rules that decide whether a year is leap or not, a year should be divisible by 4 and for those years that are divisible by 100, it should also be divisible by 400.

```
int year;
cout << "Enter a year: ";
cin >> year;

if (year%4 == 0) {
    if (year%100 == 0) {
        if (year%400 == 0) {
            cout << year << " is a leap year.";
        }
        else {
            cout << year << " is not a leap year.";
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << year << " is a leap year.";
    }
}
else {
    cout << year << " is not a leap year.";
}

return 0;}
```