# Convert seconds since last sunday midnight to date and time

Tags: c++, time, embedded-linux, utc

I know how many seconds have passed since last sunday midnight UTC. Is it possible to retrieve current UTC date and time from this information?

I have an idea as to how to get time (modulo) but what about date? I can't wrap my head around it because of leap days, years, etc..

Comment: A library might simplify things by abstracting away the gory details of time keeping. Of course, that depends on your language and I don't know which you're using

Comment: I've added some tags. So, I'm working on embedded Linux with pretty limited options considering library usage. I'm more or less limited to c++ (C++03) built-in metods and [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html).

Comment: Ouch! I was hoping for an easy `import datetime; datetime.fix_all_my_problems()` python solution :D The clock/calendar maths shouldn't be too hard but leap days/years might be another matter (as you clearly know). Some SO links: [converting-number-of-days-to-years-including-leap-years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609769/efficient-algorithm-for-converting-number-of-days-to-years-including-leap-years) and [leap-year-calculation-homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591853/leap-year-calculation-homework)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get date anyways.

Comment: Maybe not. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076494/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-c?rq=1) has some good code and interesting comments that really highlight the issues. I know you're dealing with UTC rather than "UTC to local time", but it's a good read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only retrieve a date of point `B` with `B = A + n` if you know the date for `A`. This calculation is not trivial in no aspect, as our calendar is so complex. Btw: `last sunday` is only a relative date.

With BusyBox you can try to use the `date` tool that is able to do calculations such as

```
date +"%s" --date="last sunday"
```

for you. For example (with `n = number of seconds passed from last sunday`)

```
A_s=$(date +"%s" --date="last sunday")
let 'B_s=A_s + n'
date -u --date="@""${B_s}"
```

called as a shell script from your code.