# Check Leap Year - without using division operation

Tags: java, algorithm, leap-year

How to check if the given year is a leap year, without using division operation or 
some library method in Java. Is it possible to check this using a bitwise operator?

PS: validation not necessary for centuries

Comment: Does the modulo operator (`%`) count as an option? And just out of curiosity, why is division not an option?

Comment: @n247s Likely a homework challenge for a student. Otherwise, the simple solution would be: `java.time.Year.isLeap( 2018 )`

Comment: Can you just put in the question whether you have to check for centuries?

Comment: `return ((year & 3) == 0;` To check century years you need modulo (which is a division operation): `return ((year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0));` More at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595914/733805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ways of identifying leap years without using a modulo function.

Firstly, let’s assume (or test) that the year is in the range `1901 - 2099`.

- A leap year expressed as a binary number will have `00` as the
  last two digits. So:

  it’s a leap year `if year & (not 4) == 0`
- If you have a function available to truncate a real number to an
  integer then this works:

  `x = trunc(year / 4)`

  it’s a leap year `if x * 4 == year`
- If you have shift (not circular shift) operators, which I’m sure
  Verilog has then:

  `x = year >> 2`

  it’s a leap year `if (x << 2) == year`

If the assumption about the range being `1901 - 2099` is false then you’ll need some extra logic to eliminate `1900, 1800, 1700 and 2100, 2200, 2300 and so on`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, sure.  Since division or mod by powers of 2 (in this case, 4), is just a bit check.

```
boolean isLeapYear( int year ) {
    return (( year & 3 ) == 0 );  // if the bottom two bits are 0, then the int is divisible by 4
}
```

Note this isn't perfect, as some centuries aren't leap years, but it seems that's not relevant to your question (as you now state).

Answer (score 1):

- If a year is a century year, meaning divisible by **100**, then it needs to be divisible by **400** to be called as a **leap year**.
- If a year is not a century year, then it needs to be divisible by **4** to be called as a leap year.

Below Code uses **binary search** to check if a number is divisible by another number or not(since `/` is not allowed, I am not sure if you could use `%` though).

```
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        return isDivisible(1,year,100,year) ? isDivisible(1,year,400,year) : isDivisible(1,year,4,year);
    }

    private static boolean isDivisible(int low,int high,int divisor,int dividend){
        int mid = 0;
        while(low <= high){
            mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);
            int result = divisor * mid;
            if(result == dividend) return true;
            else if(result > dividend) high = mid - 1;
            else low = mid + 1;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it without using any arithmetic operations. Use a Map which maps from year to a boolean - whether the year is a leap year or no.

Comment: So, individually add values to map?

Answer (score 0):

```
Year.isLeap(someYear)
```

You should be more specific with your requirements, this is a site for programmers :)