# Why use identical statements?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am doing a course on Udemy and I'm confused by the solution to the problem. The problem is to create a function that determines whether a year is a leap year.

The solution is:

```
function isLeap(year) {
    
/**************Don't change the code above****************/    
    
    //Write your code here.    
if (year % 4 === 0){

if (year % 100 === 0){

if (year % 400 === 0){

  return ("Leap year.")
}
} else {

  return ("Leap year.")

}
} else {

  return ("Not leap year.")

}
isLeap(1948);

    

/**************Don't change the code below****************/    

}
```

I am confused by the use of `else return ("Leap year")` when it is already used above for if those conditions are met. Am I missing something to do with how the code flows?

Comment: If you fix your braces and indentation you'll see what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isLeap(year) {
    /**************Don't change the code above****************/

    //Write your code here.
    if (year % 4 === 0) {
        if (year % 100 === 0) {
            if (year % 400 === 0) {
                return "Leap year.";
            }
        } else {
            return "Leap year.";
        }
    } else {
        return "Not leap year.";
    }
    isLeap(1948);

    /**************Don't change the code below****************/
}
```

First of all you need to format your code properly. You can use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAzArlMMCW0AEOAzgDJwCGADgBQCeFATgJT7AA6U+X+A9AFQDBQoQBFoAchj4wAC3JQA5nHwwZyyABNl5AEYQAbnGHHhPDh268eAdQY54+WhHQNpELfjUM4AOgvccVHw6RnwAUnwAFnwAXjj8AAYWdk5LAKCQ8lcIgEYEhNj4pNZ-NLTA4Pos8Kj8wpjE5NKylu8YF042EDIqR0Y-EABuZpb8AF8R7jH8OAAbImUU0cs2jvwunso+rIHh1LKJ-fGZ+cXJrlWGTpAAOQgpWYotqoZd5sPLYk3qHIBOSIAHEw9s1+CZjGIoJJpHJFMpVOp3ModHMIAB3cHgsxQQ4gAA0IAglFw0CIyFAWQY6IAClkEGSUORZmjyLQyQSdAxyGAANZwGAAZUo3JwimQMAY6DgBLgAFsURotBoSPIFOhyEoAGIQBiy8gwXBixnoGAQfEgGQwWWzawyexwIjCsBwAX0+w4fT2WjIcBEdkgUULBgwalchR65CoJkLAkAKyIAA8AEJc3n8gXkWVwEiiuCR6PSkDxhMC0UKR4ARXQ9zzSCjpwJwoYQZ9Ol0c3NlDssGsOA0qmQAISjapC1sVB9XYdcAYhnNAEdq-BQ0SGSByEQALRQOBwJXm7yLnDeUMaiN1gsEhaynDiyWFohlytL2v1mMgGC6Xv9mTISIEiVyBwWYywAYQgWVzxAB0AFZzXQBYABVdAZN9C30KUAEkoC0WABTAOxiQAQRwgUYFoR581OMYxiAA) for that.
If you do this you'll notice that everything is fine with this snippet and this algorithm actually matching one presented on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

It's worth mention that this algorithm is inefficient and if you want to read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595914/8442026) is great place to start :)

Comment: Thank you Gregooroo, I appreciate the advice.